# Why is BitArray faster than array of bools?

Tags: c#, performance

I have this implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes in C#:

```csharp
public static BitArray Count()
{
    const int halfSize = MaxSize / 2;
    var mark = new BitArray(halfSize);

    const int max = halfSize - 2;
    var maxFactor = (int) Math.Sqrt(MaxSize + 1) / 2;

    for (var i = 1; i <= maxFactor; ++i)
    {
        if (mark[i]) continue;
    
        var p = i + i + 1;
        var k = p * p >> 1;
    
        for (; k <= max; k += p)
        {
            mark[k] = true;
        }
    }

    return mark;
}
```

It gives results good enough for me. Nonetheless, I decided to test this algorithm using arrays of bools, expecting it to use more memory but be faster. And to my surprise that wasn't the [result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDcgy.png) Benchmark.NET on .NET Core 3.1 shows that bool array is more than two times slower than BitArray. Considering that latter uses more method calls and gives much longer asm ([BitArray](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) vs. [bool array](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)), how is it possible?

```
+---------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
| Method        | Mean     | Error   | StdDev  | Median   | Min      | Max      | Op/s  | Allocated |
+---------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
| SieveBool     | 294.7 ms | 4.00 ms | 3.74 ms | 293.5 ms | 290.8 ms | 304.0 ms | 3.393 | 33.38 MB  |
+---------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
| SieveBitArray | 130.2 ms | 1.03 ms | 0.97 ms | 130.3 ms | 128.5 ms | 132.1 ms | 7.680 | 4.17 MB   |
+---------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
```

Results are similar when using fields instead of initializing arrays in methods (except there is no allocation of course).

Comment: The space savings might make the difference between the array fitting into the CPU cache or not (or at least drastically change the cache hit rate). Or you're limited by memory bandwidth.
You'll probably get different results for different values of MaxSize.

Comment: As a rule of thumb. Less memory in general means higher performance. Because less memory means also less memory allocations which are in general slow. The next which has impact is cacheing in general. Prefetching, cache hits and misses, which depends on data structures. If you haven't you yould profile and remove allocating memory from your profiling and look if there's a difference. Using bits you can have states inside 4 bytes. But with booleans you need 32 * 4 bytes for your states.

Comment: `GC` kicks in? 30+ MB will make a difference. Measure it!

Comment: Memory is not for free.  BitArray is 8 times smaller, fits in the L2 cache in this test.  bool[] does not, L3 and RAM access hurts.  k += p makes the memory access pattern quite unfriendly and makes L2 crucial.